# Android TextureView not clipping to it's view-bounds on Android KitKat 4.4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.4-kitkat, android-video-player, android-textureview

I'm using a TextureView to show a cropped video by setting a scale-matrix with `setTransform(matrix)` like in [this tutorial](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/video-cropping-with-texture-view/21). So the video gets larger than the view itself.
This works fine for all android versions except for KitKat (4.4).

The problem I have here is that the TextureView's content is not cropped at the view-bounds - it draws the cropped-away part of the video too. However, the outside part is only updated when the layout refreshes (scroll).

A cropped video (nature.mp4) should look like this:

[image: state on lollipop]

This is what it looks like on KitKat (I'm showing layout bounds in this screenshot):

[image: state on kitkat]

I tried setting clip-bounds to the view-bounds via `setClipBounds(..)` - that's not working. Also, I can't use `Canvas.clipRect(..)` since TextureView's draw-method is final.

It's clearly a bug with KitKat, but has anyone an idea for a workaround?

Comment: I am also having same problem.Do you have any solution for this? or have you find the solution? please help